# Creating a functionality or process which allows client to approve comments

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I recently completed a website, built in ReactJS, for a personal trainer.

Now my client is asking if its possible for me to allow his clients to submit a testimonial on the testimonial page and it can go on the website as an immediate update only after she has approved the comment.

I am still relatively new to backend. I do have knowledge of PHP, Python and a little NodeJs.

Can someone please let me know what in your opionion is the best approach for something like this?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your backend coded in? What do you store your data in? (MongoDB, Mysql etc.)

Comment: I didnt really need to use backend as the website was mostly front-end based to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

Approach -

In your testimonial table keep a field called `approved` and keep it false by default for all the records.
Now for the client Interface show all the testimonials created by the user and if the testimonial is good or can be approved set the state of approved to true.

Now while fetching the testimonials keep a check on the backend query like  -

`select * from testimonial where client=anyone and approved = true`

Now the testimonials visible to users are only those which are approved.

But the client can see all the testimonials with status and you can provide actions to change the status on button click to true or false.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesstion Dlucidone. Can I achieve that with something like PHP?

Comment: 100% possible in PHP, there are a good number of PHP backend frameworks that you could consider using.

Comment: Nice...Thank you for the response Dane!